# ie6 ul list display inline-block expend to full width bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Working on a project these days, run into a weird problem under ie6, (ie7 and other are all ok)

Li element under a ul using display:inline-block will expend to full width. You can check the img I uploaded below.

I am using the zoom:1 *display:inline to trigger display:inline-block for lte IE8, it works fine under IE7, but IE6 has the problem above.

Here is the code

```
            <div class="mp-pagnation">
            <ul class="mp-pagnation-list clearfix">
                <li><a href="">&lt;</a></li>
                <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="">...</a></li>
                <li><a href="">654</a></li>
                <li><a href="">&gt;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    .mp-pagnation{
    width:300px;
    height:28px;
    background:#fff;
    margin:0 auto; 
    *margin-top:20px;
    padding:4px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.mp-pagnation-list{
    height:24px;
}
.mp-pagnation-list li{
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;
}

.mp-pagnation-list li a{
    display: block;
    height:24px;
    padding:0px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#00BAFF;
    margin:0px 5px;
    font-size:16px;
}
.mp-pagnation-list li a:hover,.mp-pagnation li a.current{
    color:#fff;
    background:#00BAFF;
}
```

the snapshot of the bug:
[image: bugs under ie6]

Answer (score 0):

Only supported in IE6 and IE7 on elements with a display of `inline` by default.

Try: `li{*display:inline;*zoom:1;}`

Bonus url: http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/